# How are user defined properties extracted from an ERWIN data model, and stored in the Ab Initio EME?

Tags: ab-initio

I believe this can be done using the erwin 2 eme connector graph. What are the steps involved in setting this up? How are user defined properties stored in the EME?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the connector graph is the way to go. It's not hard to set up but it's not easy either. As you've seen, Stack Overflow isn't a very good place to get info about Ab Initio. You'd be better off posing your question to support@abinitio.com or on the dedicated Ab Initio Forum accessible through the GDE. The Forum is monitored by numerous Ab Initio users and employees, and you're pretty much guaranteed to get a prompt response.